# Prestashop 1.7 register smarty related products tag

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

**Introduction**

I need to display related products from a product in a different place than prestashop's deffault (however, the theme needs to be capable to show prestashop's default related products block).

I was searching a lot about this and all I can find are modules, tutorials for **`<1.6 version`** etc.

I'm using **`1.7.2`** and those examples don't work to me.

**My Expectation**:

Register some smarty to use it after and wherever to display product attributes from a related product I want (individually).

**For example**

`{$product.id.accessory.reference}` or `{$product.id.accessory.image}`,

same with name, description and price.

**I suppose it could be**

```
{foreach $accessory ...}
{$accessory.name}
{$accessory.price}
{/foreach}
```

I'll have only a related product for some products, but i would like to keep a multi-referred product code to ensure it will be useful to everybody.

I'm surprised that prestashop has this functionallity but it's shown on a single place by default (if active) and i didn't found any tag to apply it on another place. Using {debug} i can't see accessory, accessories or related on anywhere.

The point is that we need some steps to reach it and i sincerelly don't know prestashop's core, nor how it deals with smarty or database. I would like to code a custom shop but this is where i'm working now...

i tried this answer but i can't reach the expected:
[Prestashop: How to get accessories for product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600882/prestashop-how-to-get-accessories-for-product)

Any help will be great, thanks!

*** EDIT ***

I tried accessing the public static function through smarty    `{Product::getAccessoriesLight(intval($cookie->id_lang), $product.id)}`

if i var_dump it:

`{Product::getAccessoriesLight(intval($cookie->id_lang), $product.id)|@var_dump}`

I get:

array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id_product"]=> string(3) "963" ["reference"]=> string(15) "CFPS SAH0-M11-L" ["name"]=> NULL } }

so it's working for getting the product id and the reference, not taking the name (donno why). I'll try another function so and try to discover how to show a single value.

Comment: Where you want to show related products?

Answer (score 0):

** **SOLVED** **

prestashop return an array of objects or objects with arrays. Sometimes an array with only a position and this position is an array too. Smarty deals with arrays starting at position 1 depending on the case. It's all a bit confusing logically.

What i did:

create a public static method to access non-static ones (example 1) or create a static method to query something and get results (in which case, using executeS you'll receive the bulk data like the example 2:

```
{assign var=foo value=Product::getSomethingNew($product.id)}
```

returns

```
Object(Product)->values|attrArray->values
```

in which case, you can do `{$foo.value}` or `{assign var=data value=$foo->attrArray}` then `{$data.value}`

In the second case, you'll get:

```
Array[1]->array[data] so you can simply: {$foo[1].value}
```

And obviously, it works wherever you need as you create your own methods to access data.

I didn't found the logic or the reason for some arrays to being null at 0 index but having values from index 1 and others start normally at index 0 but... I was getting different attribute values on a product object for the same ID so i don't mind on investigate too much on prestashop. It seems a school project that went too far...

Hope it helps someone.